# Python Variable is not Defined

Tags: python, text-files

Currently my code has a main menu, it asks the user to choose from the option it prints out, this is inside a 'def' function. At the end of the variable I define, there is a input prompt to ask the user for their input named 'option'. However when i run the code i get a syntax. i.e:

The code:

```
def main_menu():
        print ("\nMain Menu        ")
        print ("\n1. Alphabetical Order (Highest Score only) = 'alpha'")
        option = input ("\nEnter your Option:  ")

main_menu()

option_class = input("\nWhich Class do you wish to preview: ")
one = "1.txt"

if option == "alpha".lower():
        if option_class == "1":
                with open (one, "r") as r:
                        for line in sorted(r):
                                print (line, end='')
```

when running the code I receive the following syntax:

```
NameError: name 'option' is not defined
```

Comment: the variable option is defined inside def main_menu(), so outside the function, it does not exists..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option is locally defined. You can return entered value from function and assign it to option like this:

```
def main_menu():
    print ("\nMain Menu        ")
    print ("\n1. Alphabetical Order (Highest Score only) = 'alpha'")
    return input ("\nEnter your Option:  ")

option = main_menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `option` is only defined locally in your function `main_menu()`, not globally.

Comment: is there anyway I can make it so that it is global however still be recalled to when needed?

Comment: Ok, its all good, i understand. ill just have to take away the local variable and refer to it every time i use the function.

Answer (score -1):

The variable `option` is only local to the function `main_menu`. You can fix it by making `option` global:

```
def main_menu():
    global option
    #...
    option = '...'
```

See: [Global vs local variables](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php)

Comment: To the down voter: what is wrong with this solution?